# Help with problem with AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, menu

ive been looking and i cant find anything that solves my issue.

Im new in AS3 and i used to do this really easy in AS2.

Im building a website and i want that every time they click in a different menu link the menu box closes and opens and at the same time it loads a different swf inside.

Please if someone can help me i used to this this with variable and on enter frame but now in AS3 i have no idea.

Thanks and any advice will help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by closes and opens at the same time, anyways:

Here is the code you would use to load an SWF:

```
function loadSWF(url:String):void
{
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();

    loader.load(req);

    addChild(loader);
}

loadSWF("http://projectavian.com/projects/swf/what_in_space.swf"); //example
```

Just put loadSWF("your_file_here") into your button click code. If you want to add the SWF to a certain container, just specify that in front of addChild(loader). eg myMovieClip.addChild(loader);

Hope this helps.